# Empty Object don't override in Merge using JSON.net

Tags: c#, merge, json.net

I have this code, for merge 2 json (complete and partial). There is a empty object.

```
string jsonOrigen = @"
 {
     'business': {
         'tradingaccount': [
             '60325f59-6bef-418a-69a1-08db40bce9af',
             '054ae632-9b82-4644-6e8c-08db45721efd'
         ],
         'campaign': [
             'cf308053-3118-4e92-7bb7-08db73cba4df',
             '5ad21da9-337a-4afc-7bb8-08db73cba4df'
         ],
         'service': [
             'ab14b586-38d8-41a2-01d4-08db86a59448',
             'adac9392-d602-4874-01d5-08db86a59448'
         ]
     }
 }";

 string jsonParcial = @"{ 'business': {} }";

 JObject tokenOrigen = JObject.Parse(jsonOrigen);
 JObject tokenParcial = JObject.Parse(jsonParcial);

 tokenOrigen.Merge(tokenParcial, new JsonMergeSettings
 {
     MergeNullValueHandling = MergeNullValueHandling.Merge
 });

 string res = tokenOrigen.ToString(Formatting.Indented);
```

The output should be

> ```
>     "business": {}
> ```

but is

```
 {
  "business": {
    "tradingaccount": [
      "60325f59-6bef-418a-69a1-08db40bce9af",
      "054ae632-9b82-4644-6e8c-08db45721efd"
    ],
    "campaign": [
      "cf308053-3118-4e92-7bb7-08db73cba4df",
      "5ad21da9-337a-4afc-7bb8-08db73cba4df"
    ],
    "service": [
      "ab14b586-38d8-41a2-01d4-08db86a59448",
      "adac9392-d602-4874-01d5-08db86a59448"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that is should override while method is called merge ?

Comment: The docs says this about MergeNullValueHandling.Merge : 'The content's null value properties will be merged. ', and it is merged indeed. Did you try with Ignore instead ?
Another thing you could try (with either settings because the doc is not very explicit on this topic) is to manually add null values to your partial json for those three properties ?

Comment: if you need empty `business` then do remove this property and add empty object like `tokenOrigen.Remove("business");
tokenOrigen.Add("business", new JObject());` ... if you need `business` to be `null` then `jsonParcial` should be `{ 'business': null }`

Comment: generic method not named any property ? `propertyValue.HasValues, tokenOrigen.ContainsKey(propertyName)`  Merge works fine with `{ 'business': null }`

Comment: `JToken.Merge()` does a recursive, deep merge.  Is that what you want?  Or do you want a shallow merge where only the properties at the root level are merged while old property values are overwritten with new values?

Answer (score 0):

[`JContainer.Merge()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/MergeJson.htm) is designed to do a deep merge where the values of properties with identical names are [recursively merged](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JObject.cs#L181).  Since the empty `"business"` object has no properties, it has nothing to merge in and the original `"business"` object is unchanged.

If you want a shallow merge where the properties values of `tokenParcial` replace the property values of `tokenOrigen` you can do so easily with LINQ:

```
var query = tokenParcial.Properties().Concat(tokenOrigen.Properties())
    .GroupBy(p => p.Name)
    .Select(p => p.First()); // First() takes the properties of tokenParcial before those of tokenOrigen
var merged = new JObject(query);

string res = merged.ToString(Formatting.Indented);
```

As required, this results in:

```json
{
  "business": {}
}
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5EX0dQ).